# How to extend a users session server side?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I'm using SimpleMembership with ASP.NEt MVC.

I have a session time out of 30 minutes, on a sliding scale.

There are times that I would like to reset the timer for say user 105, without them clicking on a link, with server side logic. Is there a way I can reset a users session timer with server side code?

Comment: Where are you setting the timeout for the session? In IIS or code?

Comment: I have it set in the web.config

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible. I am pretty certain that if you change the timeout using the Configuration object, it will reset all of the sessions to an invalid state (timing them out immediately). It would be effectively the same thing as restarting the app pool.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to reset a specific user session state I would suggest creating a webservice that runs on a timer when a page loads.

EX:
Create a Javascript function on document.ready or on body load and create a timer using setInterval. In there you can make an ajax call to your webservice. In the webservice you can check who the current user is. At that point in time you can have some logic that resets the session. The point is that at every given interval the session will reload and all the user has to do is navigate to the page.

Hope this helps. If you want more code examples, just tell me what specific parts you want to see.